# Generate random numbers that can be divided by 2

Tags: java, random, numbers

I need to generate random numbers that can be divided by 2
so : 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 .....

My code looks like:

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt(20);
```

Hopefully you know what I want and you can help me.

Comment: Or just multiply the result by 2.

Comment: How many duplicate `rand%2 != 0` inferior solutions do we need?

Answer (score 5):

Just multiply i by 2

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt(20) * 2;
```

And adjust the random upper bound if you want to stay under 20 (replace by 10)

```
int i = random.nextInt(10) * 2;
```

The loop version is too heavy and ineficient in my opinion

Comment: "The loop version is too heavy and ineficient in my opinion" - could not agree more

Answer (score 4):

Simply:

```
int number = new Random().nextInt(10) * 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the remainder/modulus of the result and if it is 1, add 1 to i to give an even number:

```
Random random = new Random();
int i = random.nextInt(20);
if(i%2 == 1){
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deterministic approach -

```
Random random = new Random();
...
private int generateRandomDividedByTwo(){
   int i = -1;
   do{
      i = random.nextInt(20);
   }while(i%2!=0);
   return i;
}
```

Comment: Why even bother generating odd numbers?

Comment: make sure your random with with in range. ;)... deterministic approach

Answer (score -1):

```
int number = 100; //number of numbers you want to generate
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    int rand = random.nextInt(number);
    while(rand % 2 != 0) {
        rand = random.nextInt(number);
    }
    System.out.println(rand);
}
```

Comment: Could potentially loop for a while

Comment: @SteveKuo it depends on how bi is the Limit number if its too big then yeah